# Autohotkey_L numeric comparison issue

Tags: object, comparison, ocr, autohotkey, numeric

I have a script looping for 8 numbers, skipping negative and return the largest as follows:

```
biggest = 0
entry = 0
loop, 8
    {
    ; MsgBox %A_Index%
    if NegativeReadings%A_Index% not contains - ;filter out readings that are negative
        {
        ; MsgBox % AttributeReadings%A_Index%
        MsgBox %biggest%
        ; MsgBox % AttributeReadings%A_Index%
        if (AttributeReadings[A_Index] > biggest)
            {
            biggest := AttributeReadings[A_Index]
            entry = %A_Index%
            }
        }
    }
MsgBox %entry%
```

When I feed in some a sample image with 100,100,150,100,50,100,110,75, the OCR returns the object array result correctly but the numeric comparison fails

I'm getting MsgBox %biggest% = 0,100,100,150,**150,50**,50,50 => %entry% = 8

Something wrong happens in between (50 > 150) I have little clue in dealing with data types in ahk, any help is welcomed

Comment: You are probably comparing values alphabetically rather than by value. >>NegativeReadings%A_Index% not contains -<< is not a good way to check if a number is negative. Also check your values before loop and inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out on second shot tonight, the OCR is returning a string with tailing spaces, so it led to alphabetic comparison as mentioned by admin.

Trimmed it with regexp now it works just fine
Here is the code snippet for anyone who may come across this similar issue

```
#SingleInstance force
#Include OCR.ahk

; sleep 5000
OCR()
; global
    {
    AttributeReadings := Object()
    loop, 8
        {
        NegativeReadings%A_Index% := GetOCR(730, (136 + (17 * (A_Index - 1))), 35, 17)
        AttributeReadings[A_Index] := GetOCR(730, (136 + (17 * (A_Index - 1))), 35, 17, "numeric")
        ; MsgBox % AttributeReadings%A_Index%
        }
    biggest = 0
    entry = 0
    i = 0
    loop, 8
        {
        ; MsgBox %A_Index%
        if NegativeReadings%A_Index% not contains - ;filter out readings that are negative
            {
            ; MsgBox % AttributeReadings%A_Index%
            ; length := StrLen(biggest)
            ; MsgBox %biggest%, %length%
            number := RegExReplace(AttributeReadings[A_Index], "([space])?", "")
            MsgBox %number%
            ; MsgBox % AttributeReadings%A_Index%
            if (number > biggest)
                {
                biggest := number
                entry := i
                }
            }
            i++
        }
    MsgBox %entry%
    }
End::
OCR()
return
```

The code above basically reads in a list of numbers from an image and return the first largest non-negative. As to the negative filtering part, it's done in OCR since it's ok with my test cases, you may want to modify it depending what images you're working with